# service worker: cached data again loads from server, fetch is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, service-worker, service-worker-events

Hence manifest is deprecated, trying to implement service worker in express web application.
and this is my project structure :

```
    app.js
    views  >
            login > 
                   login.ejs 
    public >
        lib
        css
        images
        html
        js
        sw.js
```

And in my express app i am using the public folder like this :

```
app.use("/static", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

login.ejs template rendered & inside login.ejs having the code for serviceworker load

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
    });
}
```

And the registration is successfull.

And sw.js

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'v3'

// list of files
const URLS_TO_CACHE = [
    "/static/images/favicon.ico",
    "/static/lib/bootstrap/img/off.png",
    "/static/lib/bootstrap/img/on.png",
    "/static/html/help/lib/css/style.css",
    "/static/lib/templates/login/account.js"
];

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
    console.log("[Service Worker] install");
    event.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
        console.log("[Service Worker] Caching app shell");
        return cache.addAll(URLS_TO_CACHE);
    })
        .then(function () {
            self.skipWaiting();
        }));
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function (keyList) {
            return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
                if (key !== CACHE_NAME) {
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
                    return caches.delete(key);
                }
            }));
        })
    );
    return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', e =>{
    console.log("service worker : fetching");
    e.respondWith(
        fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request))
        )
});
```

Install & activate listeners are worked fine and urls are cached into cache storage as well.

when the same application reload or page navigation, fetch is not triggering and never load data from service worker always loads from server.

but when i tried in different browser tab for eg : `http://localhost:3000/static/lib/bootstrap/img/off.png` its load from service worker's fetch.

when i researching i got to know about the scope, but here i hope my sw.js file is already in top scope,

my expected behavior is : on each page load/navigation cached urls to be used instead of server call,
please suggest any workaround for this

Comment: Does your index html page comes under service worker scope?

Answer (score 0):

finally resolved the scope issue, moved the sw.js file from static to project root(parallel to app.js) and used like below, the problem solved.

```
app.use('/sw', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/sw.js')));
```

And changed the login.ejs as like below

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
    });
}
```